# How to solve a differential equation $(e^x+2\ln y)ydx+xdy=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the following differential equation:
>   $$
> (e^x+2\ln y)ydx+xdy=0
> $$

It is clear that the equation is not exact. So, I tried to express $y'$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
e^xy+2y\ln y+xy'=0\iff
\begin{cases}
\left[ 
\begin{aligned}
&y\equiv0\\
&y\equiv e^{-{1/2}}
\end{aligned}
\right. \ \ \text{if}\ \ x=0\\
y'=-\frac{e^x}{x}\cdot y-\frac{1}{x}\cdot2y\ln y\ \ \ \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
$$
The problem is that the differential equation seems to be non-linear, and I don't know the ways of solving those. Maybe there's an easier way of solving the initial differential equation?

Comment: This equation is exact if you mutliply by integrating factor $\mu (x,y)=\dfrac x y$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe there's an easier way of solving the initial differential equation? Yes. This equation becomes exact if you mutliply by integrating factor $$\mu (x,y)=\dfrac x y$$

---

$$(e^x+2\ln y)ydx+xdy=0$$
Divide by $y$ note that $ d(\ln y )=\dfrac {dy}{y}$
$$(e^x+2\ln y)dx+xd \ln y=0$$
Substitute $u= \ln y$
$$(e^x+2u)dx+xdu=0$$
Multiply by $x$:
$$xe^xdx+2uxdx+x^2du=0$$
$$xe^xdx+d(ux^2)=0$$
Integrate.
$$xe^x-e^x+x^2 \ln y =C$$

Comment: In particular, multiplication by $g:=x$ is mandated by requiring$$0=[ge^x+2gu]_u-(xg)_x=g_u(e^x+2u)+g-xg_x,$$so it helps to take $g_u=0$ and $g_x=g/x$, i.e. $g\propto x$.

Comment: Yes that's true @J.G.

Comment: Easily comprehensible and neat solution. Thank you!

Comment: @Bonrey Thank you... you're welcomed.